# get the Current Location with LocationCliant

Tags: android, google-maps

I followed what was written in
[this link,](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)
This link is an article on developer.android.com, it describes and explains how to get the user's location by the Class LocationClient. 
I followed the instructions but I added a marker on the map and focus on the location that I got. 
When I tried to run the application I got a message that the operation of the application was stopped. 
I debged the code and I think that the problem is around the function

```
getMyLocation()
```

What am I missing? I would be happy if you could help me. 
Below is the full code:

```
package ebookfrenzy.com.mapdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    LocationClient mLocationClient;
    LatLng latLngOfMyLocation;

    // Global constants
    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int
            CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    // Define a DialogFragment that displays the error dialog
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;
        // Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }
        // Set the dialog to display
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }
        // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }
    /*
     * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity
     * by Google Play services
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Decide what to do based on the original request code
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST :
            /*
             * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try
             * to connect again
             */
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                    /*
                     * Try the request again
                     */
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
    private boolean servicesConnected() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.
                        isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d("Location Updates",
                    "Google Play services is available.");
            // Continue
            return true;
            // Google Play services was not available for some reason.
            // resultCode holds the error code.
        } else {
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    resultCode,
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment =
                        new ErrorDialogFragment();
                // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
                // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                        "Location Updates");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }




    /*
    * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
    * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
    * request the current location or start periodic updates
    */
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
     * Location Services fails.
     */
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            showDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_demo);
        //the message of the location service
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Make sure your location services are turned on, whether not do you want turn them on?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        latLngOfMyLocation = new LatLng(getMyLocation().getLatitude(),getMyLocation().getLongitude());
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    /*
    * Called when the Activity becomes visible.
    */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect the client.
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }
    /*
     * Called when the Activity is no longer visible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    //Setting pop-up window and is derivatives
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Yes button clicked
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
                //Setting up the map settings
                UiSettings mapSettings;
                mapSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
                //Approval to the application to use location services
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                //lock all options built-in buttons in google maps without locking their abilities
                mapSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                mapSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
                mapSettings.setCompassEnabled(false);
                /***********************************************************************************************************
                 LatLng MUSEUM = new LatLng(38.8874245, -77.0200729);
                 Marker museum = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MUSEUM).title("Museum").snippet("National Air and Space Museum"));
                 ***********************************************************************************************************/
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(changeMarker());
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLngOfMyLocation)
                .zoom(22)
                .bearing(-14)
                .tilt(70)
                .build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }

    public Location getMyLocation(){
        // Global variable to hold the current location
        Location mCurrentLocation;
        mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        return mCurrentLocation;
    }

    public MarkerOptions changeMarker(){
        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLngOfMyLocation).title("ME");

// Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon));
        return marker;

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SF, please post a stacktrace.

Comment: Are you testing this on an emulator? If yes, you'll need to start google maps app before running your app.